# Unable to run "play" command

Tags: java, playframework

I have downloaded play-2.0.1 and trying to configure it. But when i try to execute "play" command in the extracted directory of play I am getting the following message

> ```
>    _            _  _ __ | | __ _ _  _| | | '_ \| |/ _' | || |_| |  __/|_|\____|\__ (_) |_|            |__/
> ```
>
> play! 2.0.1, http://www.playframework.org
>
> This is not a play application!
>
> Use `play new` to create a new Play application in the current
>   directory, or go to an existing application and launch the development
>   console using `play` .
>
> You can also browse the complete documentation at
>   http://www.playframework.org.

Any thoughts !! I am using following version of java

> java version "1.7.0-ea"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-ea-b66)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 16.0-b06, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: the info message is rather verbose. What do you not understand? You are supposed to use "play new" in a directory of your choice (Not the directory where you extracted play)

Comment: You should start with watching and testing existing samples and reading documentation. However you should also read on-screen messages, as they verbose enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you create a new web application with `play new testApp`, you then need to go into the directory and then you can execute `play`. The play directory you just extracted contains many samples which you can run. Ex. `cd` into the folder {your extracted play directory}\samples\java\comet-clock. Once inside this folder, you can run `play` and then `run` and other commands for play.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Mac OSX 10.7. I'm supporting the op that there is room for confusion here, hence my answer.

### **The Answer:**

The command "play" alone is not the full command. You need to add new, run, or help after it.

**To create** a new play app, the command will look something like this:

```
kerr$ /Applications/play/play new HelloWorld
```

*(I dragged and dropped my downloaded binary and unzipped play folder into Applications folder, and renamed the folder to "play" to keep it simple)*

It will say "The new application will be created in /Users/kerr/HelloWorld"

**To run** the HelloWord app, the command will look something like this:

```
kerr$ cd HelloWorld
kerr$ /Applications/play/play run
```

*(Important: You don't need the app name if you run it inside it's directory, this is where I encountered my error.)*

It will say "(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console…)"

Open `http://localhost:9000` to check that it worked.

---

### **The Confusion:**

From the official installation guide, one of the steps involved asking you to type in:

```
$ play
```

And the expected result shown was meant to be:

```
new Create a new application
run Run the application in the current shell
```

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.0.1/install

However, the result I've got using play-2.2.1 after following the steps had a different result, with the glaring warning:

```
kerr$ /Applications/play/play
       _
 _ __ | | __ _ _  _
| '_ \| |/ _' | || |
|  __/|_|\____|\__ /
|_|            |__/

play 2.2.1 built with Scala 2.10.2 (running Java 1.7.0_17), http://www.playframework.com

This is not a play application!
```

And without the expected result, hence the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Use the cd command to enter the directory. Then execution method “play run XXX ”